# Plotting seasonal data, with years on top of each other in SAS?

Tags: sas, time-series

Hi I have a time series data table from October 2013 to October 2016. I would like to plot the time series from October 2013 to November 2014, October 2014 to November 2015, and October 2015 to November 2016 on top of each other on the same graph to analyze any seasonal trends.

My idea is to create separate data tables with each subsegment, but is there an easier way to do this in SAS?

This is an example of the data table I want to plot the seasonality of.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow I think here is to add a group variable that indicates, say, year, which has the same value for all rows you want plotted in one plot-grouping.

Then you use the `group` statement in whatever plot type you want.  Something like:

```
data stocks_years;
  set sashelp.stocks;
  date_year = intck('YEAR','01AUG1986'd,date,'c')+1986;
  date_month= month(date);
run;

proc sgplot data=stocks_years;
  vline date_month/response=close group=date_year stat=mean;
run;
```

This is an example of doing that to see the average close per month of the three stocks in the SASHELP.STOCKS dataset.  It is a terrible plot of course but it should give you some idea of what it would look like. Each of those differently colored lines is from a different year (aug->jul being defined as a year, with the number being the year number of aug).

Comment: Why sgplot?  GTL or bust!

Comment: GTL for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

The lead off provided by Joe gave me everything I needed. Here is the completed code for anyone else's reference.

```
%macro Plot_Seasonal_Worse_TP(tbl_name, tp, cutoff_date);
/*tp = transition probability */

proc sql;
create table &tbl_name._trim as 
    SELECT * 
    FROM &tbl_name 
    WHERE asofdt > &cutoff_date;
run;

data &tbl_name._trim;
set &tbl_name._trim;
    date_year = intck('YEAR','01NOV2013'd,asofdt,'c')+2014;
    date_month= MOD(month(asofdt)+2, 12);   /* move november and december of previous year to front of time series */
run;

proc sgplot data=&tbl_name._trim;
  vline date_month/response=&tp group=date_year;
  title &tbl_name  (&tp);
run;

%mend Plot_Seasonal_Worse_TP;
```

Output looks like this as well.

[image]

Comment: This is also a great source for gplot examples in SAS: https://support.sas.com/sassamples/graphgallery/PROC_GPLOT.html